# How do i convert an array of objects to objects of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "A", condition: true },
  { id: 4, name: "B", condition: false },
  { id: 7, name: "C", condition: true },
  { id: 11, name: "D", condition: true },
  { id: 12, name: "E", condition: false }
]
```

Sample output

```
const data = {
  0 : { id: 1, name: "A", condition: true },
  1 : { id: 4, name: "B", condition: false },
  2 : { id: 7, name: "C", condition: true },
  3 : { id: 11, name: "D", condition: true },
  4 : { id: 12, name: "E", condition: false }
}
```

I tried this way but did not get the correct keys, not sure how do i get proper keys in ascending order.

```
const arrayToObject = {
     return data.reduce((obj, item) => {
         obj[item['id]] = item
         return obj
     }, {})
 }
```

Comment: For me works just fine: ```const obj = data.reduce((t, o) => { t[o.id] = o; return t; }, {})```

Comment: You can probably just use Object.entries and Object.fromEntries.

Comment: Why are you using the id and not the index?

Comment: `{...data}`ᅠᅠᅠᅠ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.assign`

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "A", condition: true },
  { id: 4, name: "B", condition: false },
  { id: 7, name: "C", condition: true },
  { id: 11, name: "D", condition: true },
  { id: 12, name: "E", condition: false }
]

const res = Object.assign({}, data);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function accept the index as third argument, like so:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "A", condition: true },
  { id: 4, name: "B", condition: false },
  { id: 7, name: "C", condition: true },
  { id: 11, name: "D", condition: true },
  { id: 12, name: "E", condition: false }
]


const arrayToObject = (data) => {
     return data.reduce((obj, item, i) => {
         obj[i] = item
         return obj
     }, {})
 }

console.log(arrayToObject(data));
```